# PDO leak in PHP 8.1/Lumen/Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, phpunit, lumen, resource-leak

We're running a series of test cases; our code is built on Lumen.
Our PHP is 8.1.22, our database is PostgreSQL 11, and we're using Lumen 8.6 and PHPUnit 9.0 to run the tests.

When we run the tests, on some of our devs' machines, there are huge connection leaks and we end up with 341 concurrent connections. On other machines, there are no connection leaks, and the max concurrent connections is more like 10 or 11.

Our custom test-case base class looks like this:

```
abstract class TestCase extends \Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase {
// ...
    public function tearDown(): void {
        // All kinds of issues were cropping up when using database transactions.
        // Ultimately forcing the database connection to close resolved all of them.
        // This should not interfere with the transactional support as
        // the closing of the connection should rollback the transaction automatically
        $this->app->make('db')->connection('tenant')->disconnect();
        // ...
        parent::tearDown();
        // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

The bits with ellipses handle other stuff, including some stuff that involves a legacy ZF1 database connection, but that's opened at most once so can't be the issue here.

The comments about transactions are not my doing; someone else wrote them.

What's going wrong?

Comment: _"What's going wrong?"_ Something? Most parts aren't shown in your question, e.g. what if $this->app->make('db')->connection('tenant') creates a new database connection? And the connection from setUp() or else wasn't closed? Then it will remain open unless you use non-persistent connections and run each test-case in it's own process... did you? So you should make visible that you've checked the obvious parts. Apart from that $this->app->make('db')->connection('tenant')->disconnect() looks too far reaching. I understand that you have some utility there, but obviously it doesn't scale PHP+Lumen.

Comment: And which was the last known good configuration? PHP Version, Lumen Version and Postgres Version (+PDO) would be good to have with your question. -- And there is a lot of fuzz recently about PHP 8.1/8.2 changes in regard of garbage collection (gc). Have you tried with PHPUnit 10? Have you tried w/ PHP 8.2?

Comment: First off, this is in CI testing, so who cares about scaling? Second, we haven't customized any of the database-connection opening code, and third, we have two computers, each of which is running the same versions of PHP, PHPUnit, Lumen, and Postgres, exactly one of which has this issue. The tests are kind of new (before I started fixing them up in June, they'd last been updated in 2019).

I'll check the PDO versions.